# Невыгружаемое activity

Tags: java, android, activity

Есть activity c webview, в котором открывается банковская страница оплаты. Для подтверждения оплаты банк высылает sms код. Соответственно пользователь может свернуть активити и переключиться sms messenger, чтобы прочитать сообщение. Android в этот момент может выгрузить моё activity. Как можно защититься от подобного сценария? Есть ли способ запретить ос выгружать данное activity?

Comment: делайте сервис. А активити должно только отображать окно ввода. В результате, если активити будет закрыта и приложение запуститься снова, приложение обратиться к сервису, узнает, что нужно показать актвити с смс вводом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё решилось просто

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("URL"));
            } else {
                webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
            }
}
```